# UrlFetch with Proxy-Authorization header

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to make a GET request using a UrlConnection (implemented on AppEngine by UrlFetch of course).

I'm working via a proxy server and I pass a Proxy-Authorization header in my request (Java). All the requests from app engine returns 407.

Any Idea? How do I supposed to work with a proxy server from AppEngine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little experiment once and it looks like the Proxy-Authorization header is being stripped by URLFetch. It might be correct for it to strip one Proxy-Authorization header as URLFetch is a conforming HTTP/1.1 proxy, however even if I send multiple Proxy-Authorization headers they seem all to be removed. Looks like a bug to me.